# How to define the baseline with select negative number

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this:
[image]
Sample data can be get from:

```
ID <-c("1", "1", "1","1","2", "2")
Test_date <-c(-15, -8,7, 12,-3,2)
Test_Result<-c(100, 98, 78,99, 65,89)
Sample.data <- data.frame(ID, Test_date, Test_Result)
```

I need to use the biggest negative test_date's test_result as baseline. The progress is calculated using test_result divided by the baseline Test_Result. what should I do?

The final result should be something looks like this:

[image]

Many Thanks.

Comment: Nope. For ID=1, the baseline is 98, instead of 100, not the 1st test_result when it sorted by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it this way

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(Test_date > 0 | Test_date == max(Test_date[Test_date < 0])) %>% 
  mutate(progress = ifelse(Test_date > 0,
                           Test_Result / Test_Result[which.min(Test_date)],
                           NA_real_)) %>% 
  right_join(df) %>% 
  arrange(ID, Test_date) %>% 
  ungroup(ID)

Joining, by = c("ID", "Test_date", "Test_Result")
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  ID    Test_date Test_Result progress
  <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1 1           -15         100   NA    
2 1            -8          98   NA    
3 1             7          78    0.796
4 1            12          99    1.01 
5 2            -3          65   NA    
6 2             2          89    1.37
```

Comment: What if we have more test_date that are positive that we need to keep. I just updated the question codes. Thanks

Comment: how is `progress` calculated in this situation?

Comment: I just updated the post. In this case, the progress is calculated by test_1/baseline(test_1) when test_date>0/ for ID=1, date 12, the progress=99/98

Comment: Thanks so much. One silly question, what "NA_real_" means, how does that work?

Comment: if `Test_date < 0`, the `progress` calculation is not done, but set to NA (not available). Instead of `NA`, you can put `NA_real_` for numeric values

Answer (score 1):

In my view, this kind of operation "by group" operation is most easily accomplished with `dplyr` or `data.table` packages:

```
ID <-c("1", "1", "1","2", "2")
Test_date <-c(-15, -8,7, -3,2)
Test_Result<-c(100, 98, 78,65,89)
Sample.data <- data.frame(ID, Test_date, Test_Result)

big_neg <- function(x) which(x == max(x[x < 0]))

library(dplyr)
Sample.data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Progress = Test_Result / Test_Result[big_neg(Test_date)])
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>   ID    Test_date Test_Result Progress
#>   <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 1           -15         100    1.02 
#> 2 1            -8          98    1    
#> 3 1             7          78    0.796
#> 4 2            -3          65    1    
#> 5 2             2          89    1.37


library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(Sample.data)
dat[, Progress := Test_Result / Test_Result[big_neg(Test_date)], by=ID][]
#>    ID Test_date Test_Result  Progress
#> 1:  1       -15         100 1.0204082
#> 2:  1        -8          98 1.0000000
#> 3:  1         7          78 0.7959184
#> 4:  2        -3          65 1.0000000
#> 5:  2         2          89 1.3692308
```

Comment: Nope. For ID=1, the baseline is 98, instead of 100, not the 1st test_result when it sorted by date. The tricky part is we need to use the biggest negative date for baseline instead of the oldest one.

Comment: Your original definition of "biggest negative" was not super clear. I edited by simply defining a `big_neg` function.

Comment: Thanks for the updated. Is it a way to keep progress for test_date<0 as blank?

Comment: Sure, just add a new command after the ones in my post: `dat[Test_date < 0, Progress := NA]` in `data.table` or `Sample.data %>% mutate(Progress = ifelse(Test_date < 0, Progress, NA))` in dplyr.

Comment: Thanks so much! what if I want to remove the record with Test_date<0 but not the max neg? how should I achieve this?

Comment: `dat[(Test_date > 0) | big_neg(Test_date)]` or `dat %>% filter((Test_date > 0) | big_neg(Test_date))`